# Solving Lagrange equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, self-learning

Please help me solving the equation.

I found one of its solutions: $c_1=(xz)/y$

But another one is given as $c_2=(x^3/y)+x$ in the text book. But I cont find. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Rewrite the equation in terms of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$
- Make the substitution $y = v~x$
- You end up with a first order equation, use Integrating Factor

Comment: What is the second one you said? How to make the substitution ?

Comment: Where you see a $y$ substitute $vx$. Where you see a $dy/dx$, substitute $v + xv'$.

Comment: I get $dy/dx=3y/x+y^2/x^3$ and then?

Comment: Okay now I get $x^2v'=2xv+v^2$

Comment: Now do the substitutions I listed above and you have a DEQ in terms of $dv/dx$, solve that and then substitute back.

Comment: Nice direction! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, nap time! :-)

Comment: @Nrsnr: Now, rewrite that DEQ  and solve it. How did you get a $2$?

Comment: Nope I cannot remember:( altohugh you explain so good

Comment: I checked it one more times, and there is 2.